# How can I get mediawiki to email me on every db error?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I'm looking for a hook or some way to easily send out emails every time I get a database error on mediawiki. I realize that I might have to add this functionality to their database class but I'm not sure at the moment if I should be doing that.

I do not want a solution that includes daemons, crons, or anything else that'll read and send out emails based on the SQL query log.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be doing that? All it would mean is that you have to change the class again if you update MediaWiki, so just be mindful of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical way of doing this is probably registering custom exception handler. There we check if the exception is a database error and send an e-mail accordingly.

I’ve come up with this simple code:

```
$wgHooks['SetupAfterCache'][] = 'onSetupAfterCache';
function onSetupAfterCache() {
    set_exception_handler( 'customExceptionHandler' );

    return true;
}
```

First we have to set up a hook to register our exception handler. If we registered it just so in `LocalSettings.php` it would get overriden by `wfInstallExceptionHandler()`.

```
function customExceptionHandler( $e ) {
    if( $e instanceof DBError ) {
        $from = new MailAddress( 'dberror@example.com' );
        $to = new MailAddress( 'personal.mail@example.com' );
        $body = 'A database error occured on My Wiki. Details follow:' . "\n\n" .
            $e->getText();

        UserMailer::send( $to, $from, 'Database error on My Wiki', $body );
    }
```

Here we check if the exception was caused by the database and send the e-mail. You should customize the `$from`, `$to` and `$body` variables. For more info about the [`UserMailer`](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classUserMailer.html) and [`MailAddress`](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classMailAddress.html) classes see the documentation.

```
    wfExceptionHandler( $e );
}
```

In the end we pass the exception to MediaWiki’s handler, which we’ve overriden earlier. It takes care of outputting the error to the user and other important stuff.

Comment: Doing this method will also catch warning and fatal errors as well as db errors, correct? (not that I mind)

Comment: This will only catch exceptions, which occur only on fatal errors, like syntax or connection error.